# SQL Server Max File Size on Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, max, filesize

My company is going to purchase a Visual studio professional and id like to ask what are the limitations of the sql server that is inside the package. Like max file size etc.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the sql server that is inside the package'?

Comment: It comes with SQL Server Express IIRC but you can just download that separately anyway. The limitations for that are easily found. or you can get SQL Server developer edition separately (not included with VS). This has no limitations other than must only be used for development purposes.

Comment: Yes, im talking bout the SQL Server inside the package VS Professional 2012

Comment: whats the file size limitation?